# Can I get list of people searched for a topic or a tag in Google?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search

I want to get the list of users (logged in email IDs) who searched for a tag or a phrase or a word in Google.

For ex: I should get the list of users who googled for "Avengers:End Game".

Is Google providing any services of this kind or any third party tools available.

I know google trends is providing statistical data regarding google search tags but it is only a number of searches happened.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If those users are arriving on your website, you can use [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) to see what queries users found your website with.

Comment: Yep I got your point, But my case is like i need list of user email ID with which he/she logged in to the browser used for googling for a specific term as explained above.

Comment: You can't get that data

Comment: Okayy.. Thank You for the swift response... :)